# sessionStorage not immediately available

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, session-storage

In the example below (and in the jsfiddle, dependant on requirejs) the console outputs `theUsername` and `http://nothing&username=null` the first time through and then if you run it again it outputs as you'd expect (i.e., `http://nothing&username=theUsername`)

```
define('environment', {
    myData: 'http://nothing&username=' + sessionStorage.getItem('username')
});

require(['environment'], function (environment) {
    sessionStorage['username'] = 'theUsername';

    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    console.log(environment.myData);
});
```

**Previous edits**

I couldn't figure out how to set this up in a jsfiddle with all the dependencies, but here is a simple version demonstrating the problem in azure.  The page doesn't actually do anything and hits a dead connection string so you'll have to look at it through the browser dev tools or firebug.

http://tomdev.azurewebsites.net/www/index.html

Ok, hopefully the last update... I was able to get this displaying the problem in jsfiddle, very simple, small example.  Watch the console in Chrome.  Run it once and you'll see the problem, hit run again and you'll see it's working now.

http://jsfiddle.net/JhK5L/1/

Comment: Try doing a `console.log(sessionStorage['username'])` and `console.log(sessionStorage['password'])` right before the ajax call to see what their values are? I am guessing that `sessionStorage['username']` and `sessionStorage['password']` were not set before you assign the relevant value to `environment.sessionStorageEndpoints.myData`.

Comment: Yes, they're available directly before the ajax call.  I can do `console.log(sessionStorage['username/password']` and get values back, then immediately following that do `console.log(environment.myDataUrl)` and the myDataUrl comes back with `[...]userid=undefined&password=undefined[...]`

Comment: I hope I'm not being too irritating here, but do the `credentialsQueryString` and `myDataUrl` variables have the correct values?

Comment: As in did I make a typo in the code, or do they have the correct values when executed?  If typo in the code -- yes, they're correct.  If "do they have the correct values when executed," no, they're not getting any values *the first time through*.  Now, if I refresh the page (but session is still the same) it will work.

Comment: I meant the latter. Wow that's pretty strange... Try using the `setItem` and `getItem` methods of `sessionStorage` ? I'm basing it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage

Comment: I actually did just switch to them :) but essentially the same behavior (except now I'm getting `null` instead of `undefined`)

Comment: Here's an idea... Since `session['username']` and `session['password']` return the stored values, just assign those values to temporary variables and use them in constructing `credentialsQueryString`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Same situation, though; they ended up being `null`. So, this `environment` object seems to just not have any access directly after they're assigned.

Comment: and just to add one more point, I may have already said it, if I change the `url` in the ajax call to exactly what is in the `environment` object, only put it directly in the ajax call, it works.

Comment: I'm sure you've moved on from this, but I've updated the question to include a live example if seeing it for yourself may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're initializing `myData` in your `define()` call with whatever value is in `sessionStorage['username']`. Therefore, the first time you call `define()` the value is null, and is not set until you initialize `sessionStorage['username']` in your `require()` function.

Instead of initializing `myData` to a string, make it a getter function that retrieves the current value at invocation:

```
define('environment', {
    myData: function() { return 'http://nothing&username=' + sessionStorage.getItem('username'); }
});

require(['environment'], function(environment) {
    sessionStorage['username'] = 'theUsername';

    $("ul").append('<li>' + sessionStorage.getItem('username') +'</li>');
    $("ul").append('<li>' + environment.myData() +'</li>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with requiring the environment module before running the code. When you do `require(['environment'], function () {` it will find AND run the environment module BEFORE anything else gets run. This means whatever is in session storage at the time is what gets outputted. Then, it runs the function, which sets up the session storage to what it should be.

Once the function is run, you need to update the myData variable with the new value, as it has already "cached" the old one, which was undefined.